# Typescript class static data used for instance data, array not calling constructor

Tags: arrays, class, typescript

I am not getting constructor cx in the following:

```
class acx_inspector {
    acx : cx[]=[];
    el0: HTMLElement;
    constructor(el0: HTMLElement) {
        for (var indx = 0; indx <5; indx++) {
            this.acx.push(new cx());
        }
       var ix = this.acx[3].iidx;
       el0.innerText = "acx[3].iidx = " + this.acx[3].iidx.toString();
    }

}
class cx {
    public iidx: Number;
    public static iid = 0;
    constuctor() {
       this.iidx = cx.iid;
       cx.iid = cx.iid + 1;
    }
}
```

Result should be to have cx.iid make each instance have a unique iidx, and be able to check in array for instance iidx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `constructor`. Fix:

```
constructor() {
   this.iidx = cx.iid;
   cx.iid = cx.iid + 1;
}
```

Which meant you had a `constuctor` member function not the `constructor` called by `new`